# How to use classes inside headers in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

So i'm very new to c++ and i'm trying to test out the simple features it has. I currently have a problem that there is a 'class' type redefinition and I can't figure out why. I have used #pregama once in the header file, but still. I have even tried #ifndef and #define, but they did not work either. I'm using Visual studio 2019 community if that has anything to do with this.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vectors.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double distance = Vector2::Zero().Distance(Vector2(1, 1));
    cout << distance;

    return 0;
}
```

Vector2.cpp

```
#include "Vectors.h"
#include <cmath>

class Vector2 {
public:
    double x;
    double y;

    Vector2(double x, double y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    static Vector2 Zero() {
        return Vector2(0, 0);
    }
    static Vector2 One() {
        return Vector2(1, 1);
    }
    double Distance(Vector2 other) {
        Vector2 relPos = this->operator-(other);
        relPos.x = abs(relPos.x);
        relPos.y = abs(relPos.y);

        return sqrt(pow(relPos.x, 2) + pow(relPos.y, 2));
    }

    Vector2 operator + (Vector2 vec) {
        return Vector2(x + vec.x, y + vec.y);
    }
    Vector2 operator - (Vector2 vec) {
        return Vector2(x - vec.x, y - vec.y);
    }
    Vector2 operator * (Vector2 vec) {
        return Vector2(x * vec.x, y * vec.y);
    }
    Vector2 operator / (Vector2 vec) {
        return Vector2(x / vec.x, y / vec.y);
    }
};
```

Vectors.h

```
#pragma once

class Vector2 {
public:
    Vector2(double x, double y);

    static Vector2 Zero();
    static Vector2 One();
    double Distance(Vector2 other);
    Vector2 operator + (Vector2 vec);
    Vector2 operator - (Vector2 vec);
    Vector2 operator * (Vector2 vec);
    Vector2 operator / (Vector2 vec);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I agree with Silvio Mayolo, You're defining the class once in the header and once in the C++ file. You don't use the keyword class in your cpp file.

And then you need to distinguish between `class Vector2` and `Vector2(double x, double y);` As far as I'm concerned you should try to use `Vector2::`.

Here is my code:

Vectors.h：

```
#pragma once
class Vector2 {
public:
    double x;
    double y;

    Vector2(double x, double y);

    static Vector2 Zero();
    static Vector2 One();
    double Distance(Vector2 other);
    Vector2 operator + (Vector2 vec);
    Vector2 operator - (Vector2 vec);
    Vector2 operator * (Vector2 vec);
    Vector2 operator / (Vector2 vec);
};
```

Vector2.cpp：

```
#include "Vectors.h"
#include <cmath>

double x;
double y;

Vector2::Vector2(double x, double y) 
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }



     Vector2 Vector2::Zero() {
        return Vector2(0, 0);
    }


    Vector2 Vector2::One() {
        return Vector2(1, 1);
    }
    double Vector2::Distance(Vector2 other) {
        Vector2 relPos = this->operator-(other);
        relPos.x = abs(relPos.x);
        relPos.y = abs(relPos.y);

        return sqrt(pow(relPos.x, 2) + pow(relPos.y, 2));
    }

    Vector2 Vector2::operator + (Vector2 vec) {
        return Vector2(x + vec.x, y + vec.y);
    }
    Vector2 Vector2::operator - (Vector2 vec) {
        return Vector2(x - vec.x, y - vec.y);
    }
    Vector2 Vector2::operator * (Vector2 vec) {
        return Vector2(x * vec.x, y * vec.y);
    }

    Vector2  Vector2::operator / (Vector2 vec) {
        return Vector2(x / vec.x, y / vec.y);
    }
```

Main.cpp：

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Vectors.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        double distance = Vector2::Zero().Distance(Vector2(1, 1));
        cout << distance;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Saksu  Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Comment: Sorry I was away for a week so I did not answer but I have now tested the answers and this on worked wonders. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the class once in the header and once in the C++ file. You don't want to do `class Vector2 {` in the C++ file. Your functions should look like this

```
Vector2 Vector2::operator+(Vector2 vec) {
  return Vector2(x + vec.x, y + vec.y);
}
```

And should be defined at top-level scope in the C++ file.

Comment: typo? op is defining the class twice, not just declaring it

Comment: After doing that there is an error that says "qualified name is not allowed in member decleration".

Comment: Don't put it inside a `class Vector2 { ... }` block. Don't even use the keyword `class` in your cpp file.

Comment: Then it says expected an identifier